# Can Flask use the async feature of Tornado Server?

Tags: python, flask, tornado, python-asyncio

We have a project use Flask+Gunicorn(sync). This works well for a long time,  however, recently i came across to know that Asyncio(Python3.5) support async io in standard library.

However, before Asyncio, there are both Twisted and Tornado async servers. So, i wander whether Flask can use the aysncio feature of Tornado, cause Gunicorn support tornado worker class.

Comment: You can use the WSGIContainer object: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, i know that. What makes me curious is that whether we can still use Flask+Tornado to work around C10K.

Answer (score 4):

No. It is possible to run Flask on Tornado's `WSGIContainer`, but since Flask is limited by the WSGI interface it will be unable to take advantage of Tornado's asynchronous features. `gunicorn` or `uwsgi` is generally a much better choice than Tornado's `WSGIContainer` unless you have a specific need to run a Flask application in the same process as native Tornado `RequestHandlers`.